# I need help understanding the relationship between abstract classes

Tags: java, abstract

I have an assignment that I'm not quite sure where to start. This is what I'm supposed to do.

- Create an abstract class DiscountPolicy.  It will have a single abstract method computeDiscount that will return the discount for the purchase of a given number of a single item.  The method has two parameters, count  (int) and itemCost (float)
- Derive a class BulkDiscount from Discount Policy.  It will have a constructor that has two parameters, minimum and percent.  It will define a method computeDiscount so that if the quantity purchased of an item is more than the minimum, the discount is the percent for the class.  ComputeDiscount will return the total discount.
- Derive a class BuyNItemsGetOneFree from DiscountPolicy.  The class will have a constructor that has a single parameter n.  In addition, the class will define the method computeDiscount so that every nth item is free.  For example:
- If n is 3 and the item cost is $10.  There is no discount for the first 2 items.  There is a $10 discount for items 3 – 5, there is a $20 discount for the 6th item, etc.
- For BuyNItemsGetOneFree – the computeDiscount method will receive the total items bought and the cost for an item, and will return the total discount if applicable.
- In your main program, show that the computeDiscount method works for the BulkDiscount and BuyNItemsGetOneFree classes.

This is how I began to set it up. I want to make my methods and parameters are in the correct locations and am wondering where I define the parameters that my teacher wants me to pass.

```
public class Ex1012 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DiscountPolicy bulk = new BulkDiscount();

        System.out.println();

        DiscountPolicy bngo = new BuyNItemsGetOneFree();        
    }
}

public abstract class DiscountPolicy {  
    abstract void computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost){

        return discount;
    }
}


public class BuyNItemsGetOneFree extends DiscountPolicy {

    BuyNItemsGetOneFree() { 
    }

    BuyNItemsGetOneFree(int n){
        DiscountPolicy.computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost);
        //set n to a variable here??
        //calculations go here
        //Where to set count and itemCost??
    }   
}

public class BulkDiscount extends DiscountPolicy {

    public BulkDiscount(int minimum, float percent){
        if (quantity > minimum){
            super.ComputeDiscount(int count, float itemCost);
        //calculations go here
            //Where to define count, itemCost, minimum, and percent??
        }       
    }   
}
```

I'm simply worried about the relationship between the classes and the parameters themselves because I get confused once I have multiple classes such as these. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please confirm that the post looks good in the preview window before submitting.

Comment: The method parameters are provided by the caller of the method. In this case, since you create your objects in `main`, that is probably where you will provide the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract methods may not have a body, so your definition of `computeDiscount(...)` should be:

```
abstract void computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost);
```

In each of the concrete classes that extend the abstract class, you'd then have to implement that method. Generally, abstract methods behave like methods defined in interfaces to some extent (they are declared but without a default implementation), yet still have differences (can be protected or package private as well, can only be implemented by subclasses etc.).

In most cases you have an abstract class that provides some default logic and just requires the subclasses to fill in some "holes" that depend on the concrete implementation.

So basically, you store the parameters to `BuyNItemsGetOneFree` and `BulkDiscount` as instance variables and use them when `computeDiscount(...)` is called. You're calling it in the constructor, which is most likely the wrong place. I guess your main should call the method on the objects you create directly, e.g.

```
DiscountPolicy bngo = new BuyNItemsGetOneFree(5); 
double discountForFour = bngo.computDiscount(4,4.95f);
double discountForFive = bngo.computDiscount(5,4.95f);
```

Note that your `computeDiscount(...)` method should return a value, according to your assignment:

> ...a single abstract method computeDiscount that will **return** the discount for the purchase of a given number of a single item...

Edit:

> //Where to set count and itemCost??

As I said above, you don't "set" (store) them, but use them for the calculation only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to review how to define abstract methods. An abstract method does not have a body "{}". It should be defined in sub-classes. The sub-classes do the calculation of the discount generally when the base class calls the abstract method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, abstract methods do not have body.

Secondly as it should compute discount it should return it so computeDiscount canot be void it should in your case return float.

So DiscountPolicy  should look like

```
public abstract class DiscountPolicy {  
  abstract float computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost);
}
```

Furthermore you can not use

```
DiscountPolicy.computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost);
```

as computeDiscount method is not static method, it is even not concrete.

Just a note, java is case sensitive language so you should be using stuff as you declared them, computeDiscount and ComputeDiscount are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

`DiscountPolicy` is a base abstract class. This, in your case, gives a structure for a class that represents some type of Discount: all such classes should have a method computeDiscount, and this method would calculate the discount based on the respective policies. This is a contract that all classes representing a DiscountPolicy has to follow.

`DiscountPolicy` itself does not give any logic for calculating a discount (no "default policy"). Every class has to provide their own logic. You enforce it by making the `computeDiscount` method `abstract`.

An abstract method in java does not have any body. It is just the signature: just the contract (structure) and no implementation.

So the computeDiscount in your DiscountPolicy class should look like (Note the `;` at the end of the signature itself. Also no `{}`) :

```
abstract float computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost);
```

Also, this method *will return the discount for the purchase of a given number of a single item*, so the return type should be a `float` and not `void`

The `BuyNItemsGetOneFree` and `BulkDiscount` classes, being subclasses of `DiscountPolicy` *should* implement the `computeDiscount` method. The logic in the `computeDiscount` methods of the two sub classes will be different, based on the discount calculation logic for bulk discount and the buy n get 1 free (this logic is given in your exercise).

```
class BulkDiscount extends DiscountPolicy
{
   //Same signature as computeDiscount of DiscountPolicy
   //Not abstract, no semicolon at end of signature, has body. 
   //Also called "Concrete" method
   float computeDiscount(int count, float itemCost)
   {
       //The logic as given in the exercise.
       //Return the discount calculated by the logic
   }
}
```

You test these as (in `Ex1012`'s, `main` method):

```
   DiscountPolicy bulk = new BulkDiscount();
   float discount = bulk.computeDiscount(10, 1);  //Data used to test

   DiscountPolicy bngo = new BuyNItemsGetOneFree();  
   float  discount = bngo.computeDiscount()
```